# Acorn font initials not supported by tex4ebook up to now

Tags: fonts, tex4ebook

For a nice little poetry book I like to use the acorn initial fonts, which work with pdflatex fine, but in the epub with tex4ebook it does not come out. Also with the follow MWE the missing situation can be simulated. Thank you for support.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input Acorn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    {\initfamily T}his is a sentence with Acorn Intial.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for fonts provided by the `initials` package. Fortunately, it is not hard to add it. Save the following file as `Acorn.htf`:

```
Acorn 0 160
'' '' .notdef 0  % generated from Acorn.tfm, 2023-07-06-13:12
'' ''            % Copyright 2023 TeX Users Group
'' ''            %
'' ''            % This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
'' ''            % conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
'' ''            % version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
'' ''            % later version. The latest version of this license is in
'' ''            %   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
'' ''            % and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
'' ''            % of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
'' ''            %
'' ''            % This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
'' ''            %
'' ''            % The Current Maintainer of this work
'' ''            % is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
'' ''            %
'' ''            % If you modify this program, changing the
'' ''            % version identification would be appreciated.
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
' ' '' space 32
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'A' '1' A 65
'B' '1' B 66
'C' '1' C 67
'D' '1' D 68
'E' '1' E 69
'F' '1' F 70
'G' '1' G 71
'H' '1' H 72
'I' '1' I 73
'J' '1' J 74
'K' '1' K 75
'L' '1' L 76
'M' '1' M 77
'N' '1' N 78
'O' '1' O 79
'P' '1' P 80
'Q' '1' Q 81
'R' '1' R 82
'S' '1' S 83
'T' '1' T 84
'U' '1' U 85
'V' '1' V 86
'W' '1' W 87
'X' '1' X 88
'Y' '1' Y 89
'Z' '1' Z 90
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'a' '1' a 97
'b' '1' b 98
'c' '1' c 99
'd' '1' d 100
'e' '1' e 101
'f' '1' f 102
'g' '1' g 103
'h' '1' h 104
'i' '1' i 105
'j' '1' j 106
'k' '1' k 107
'l' '1' l 108
'm' '1' m 109
'n' '1' n 110
'o' '1' o 111
'p' '1' p 112
'q' '1' q 113
'r' '1' r 114
's' '1' s 115
't' '1' t 116
'u' '1' u 117
'v' '1' v 118
'w' '1' w 119
'x' '1' x 120
'y' '1' y 121
'z' '1' z 122
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
' ' '' space 160
Acorn 0 160
htfcss:  Acorn  font-family: 'Acorn Initials', serif;
```

This file contains instructions on how to process characters in the DVI file. The instructions like this:

```
'A' '1' A 65
'B' '1' B 66
'C' '1' C 67
```

require that these characters will be converted to images, thanks to the '1' value in the table.

You could also simplify your file like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{Acorn}
%\input Acorn.fd
%\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    % {\initfamily T}his is a sentence with Acorn Intial.
    \acorn{T}his is a sentence with Acorn Intial.
\end{document}
```

There is no need to include the `.fd` file or to declare the `initfamily` command. The `Acorn` package provides the `\acorn` command, which works just fine.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull michal.h21. That is again a good help for that project. I will try it and be sure, it will work also on my system. With best wishes. Thomas

Comment: @Thomkrates I hope it will work for you. I will add the support for all fonts from the `cfr-initials` bundle to TeX4ht sources, so they all should work soon in TeX Live.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it worked. That would be great, if other initals could be supported, since future sign might need other intials as well. But another problem arose (not with the intials). I will show it in another question.